# how to write JavaScript and add loop for following to do math operations when i enter value in input fields with same names?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, forms

What I am trying to do is simple math operations but with my code below I am able to apply it to only one set of inputs. But I want it do same to all set of inputs.

```js
$('.num,.numm,.gen').keyup(function() {
  var closing = parseFloat($('.num').val());
  var total = parseFloat($('.numm').val());
  var gen = $('.gen').val();
  document.getElementById('sales').innerHTML = (total - closing);
  document.getElementById('saletotal').innerHTML = ((total - closing) * gen);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" data-id="55" class="num" name="close_val[]">
<input type="hidden" name="GeneralRate[]" id="GeneralRate" class="gen" value="70.00">
<input type="hidden" id="sales1177" name="total[]" class="numm" value="711">
<label id="sales">0</label>
<label id="saletotal">0</label>

<br>

<input type="text" data-id="55" class="num" name="close_val[]">
<input type="hidden" name="GeneralRate[]" id="GeneralRate" class="gen" value="70.00">
<input type="hidden" id="sales1177" name="total[]" class="numm" value="711">
<label id="sales">0</label>
<label id="saletotal">0</label>

<br>

<input type="text" data-id="55" class="num" name="close_val[]">
<input type="hidden" name="GeneralRate[]" id="GeneralRate" class="gen" value="70.00">
<input type="hidden" id="sales1177" name="total[]" class="numm" value="711">
<label id="sales">0</label>
<label id="saletotal">0</label>
```

Comment: names and IDs should be unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to fix your ids - ids should be unique so change them to classes instead.  Then in your event, you need to get the current input that is keyupped.

From that you can use a combination of `nextAll` and `first` to get the nearest sibling with the class you are after to do your calculations and update the labels

```js
$('.num').keyup(function() {
  var $input = $(this); // get the input that has been key upped
  var closing = parseFloat($input.val());
  var total = parseFloat($input.nextAll('.numm').first().val());
  var gen = parseFloat($input.nextAll('.gen').first().val());
  var sales = total - closing;
  $input.nextAll('.sales').first().html(sales);
  $input.nextAll('.saletotal').first().html(sales  * gen);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" data-id="55" class="num" name="close_val[]">
<input type="hidden" name="GeneralRate[]" id="GeneralRate" class="gen" value="70.00">
<input type="hidden" id="sales1177" name="total[]" class="numm" value="711">
<label class="sales">0</label>
<label class="saletotal">0</label>

<br>

<input type="text" data-id="55" class="num" name="close_val[]">
<input type="hidden" name="GeneralRate[]" id="GeneralRate" class="gen" value="70.00">
<input type="hidden" id="sales1177" name="total[]" class="numm" value="711">
<label class="sales">0</label>
<label class="saletotal">0</label>

<br>

<input type="text" data-id="55" class="num" name="close_val[]">
<input type="hidden" name="GeneralRate[]" id="GeneralRate" class="gen" value="70.00">
<input type="hidden" id="sales1177" name="total[]" class="numm" value="711">
<label class="sales">0</label>
<label class="saletotal">0</label>
```

If you can change the html, I would wrap each set in it's own div and then the you could make the jquery a little neater:

```js
$('.num').keyup(function() {
  var $input = $(this); // get the input that has been key upped
  var $parent = $input.parent();
    var closing = parseFloat($input.val());
  var total = parseFloat($parent.find('.numm').val());
  var gen = parseFloat($parent.find('.gen').val());
  var sales = total - closing;
  $parent.find('.sales').html(sales);
  $parent.find('.saletotal').html(sales * gen);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input type="text" data-id="55" class="num" name="close_val[]">
  <input type="hidden" name="GeneralRate[]" id="GeneralRate" class="gen" value="70.00">
  <input type="hidden" id="sales1177" name="total[]" class="numm" value="711">
  <label class="sales">0</label>
  <label class="saletotal">0</label>
</div>
<div>
  <input type="text" data-id="55" class="num" name="close_val[]">
  <input type="hidden" name="GeneralRate[]" id="GeneralRate" class="gen" value="70.00">
  <input type="hidden" id="sales1177" name="total[]" class="numm" value="711">
  <label class="sales">0</label>
  <label class="saletotal">0</label>
</div>
<div>
  <input type="text" data-id="55" class="num" name="close_val[]">
  <input type="hidden" name="GeneralRate[]" id="GeneralRate" class="gen" value="70.00">
  <input type="hidden" id="sales1177" name="total[]" class="numm" value="711">
  <label class="sales">0</label>
  <label class="saletotal">0</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another version:

```js
$('.num').each(function(i,el) {
   const gen = +$("~ .gen", this).val();
   const numm = +$("~ .numm", this).val();
   $(this).on("input", ev => {
    let sales = numm - this.value;
    $("~ .sales:first", this).text(sales);
    $("~ .saletotal:first", this).text(sales*gen);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" data-id="55" class="num" name="close_val[]">
<input type="hidden" name="GeneralRate[]" id="GeneralRate" class="gen" value="30.00">
<input type="hidden" id="sales1177" name="total[]" class="numm" value="100">
<label class="sales">0</label>
<label class="saletotal">0</label>

<br>

<input type="text" data-id="55" class="num" name="close_val[]">
<input type="hidden" name="GeneralRate[]" id="GeneralRate" class="gen" value="50.00">
<input type="hidden" id="sales1177" name="total[]" class="numm" value="400">
<label class="sales">0</label>
<label class="saletotal">0</label>

<br>

<input type="text" data-id="55" class="num" name="close_val[]">
<input type="hidden" name="GeneralRate[]" id="GeneralRate" class="gen" value="70.00">
<input type="hidden" id="sales1177" name="total[]" class="numm" value="711">
<label class="sales">0</label>
<label class="saletotal">0</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Id are singular so you can not rely on ids. You need to use the class or name to reference the elements.

If you group them with a wrapper element, you an add one event listener to that element and easily find the inputs that relate to each other.

```js
$("fieldset").on("input", function () {
  const fs = $(this);
  const num = +fs.find(".num").val();
  const gen = +fs.find(".gen").val();
  const numm = +fs.find(".numm").val();
  fs.find(".sales").text('x' + num);
  fs.find(".saletotal").text(num + ', ' + gen + ', '+ numm);
});
```

```css
fieldset {
  border: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<fieldset>
  <input type="text" data-id="55" class="num" name="close_val[]">
  <input type="hidden" name="GeneralRate[]" class="gen" value="70.00">
  <input type="hidden" name="total[]" class="numm" value="711">
  <label class="sales">0</label>
  <label class="saletotal">0</label>
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
  <input type="text" data-id="55" class="num" name="close_val[]">
  <input type="hidden" name="GeneralRate[]" class="gen" value="70.00">
  <input type="hidden" name="total[]" class="numm" value="711">
  <label class="sales">0</label>
  <label class="saletotal">0</label>
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
  <input type="text" data-id="55" class="num" name="close_val[]">
  <input type="hidden" name="GeneralRate[]" class="gen" value="70.00">
  <input type="hidden" name="total[]" class="numm" value="711">
  <label class="sales">0</label>
  <label class="saletotal">0</label>
</fieldset>
```